# How to open recently closed file in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

I am looking for shortcut to open recently closed file in PhpStorm.

I know some similar shortcuts but I am looking for command which is the same like <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + T</kbd> in browsers...

Comment: Keyboard shortcuts available in PHPStorm are listed in their [documenatation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/keyboard-shortcuts-by-category.html). Other than that I'm not really sure this is a question for SO.

Comment: [Navigate to recent file](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/navigating-to-recent-file.html)

Comment: double pressing shift usually allows a quick open of a file if that's of use..

Comment: @Byakko_Haku I look into documentation and find similar commands like I wrote above, but I want ctrl+shift+t browser or notepad++ identically command...

Comment: @Option ctrl+e or double shift is fine, but I want ctrl+shift+t ...

Comment: It is confusing that in the menu File->Open Recent is always greyed out. Thanks for the link, @Byakko_Haku.

Comment: You also can press **double shift** and type reopen. Then select _Reopen Closed Tab_. I find my self using this very rarely so shortcut seems like an overkill for me.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

There is such a command exists already but it does not have a shortcut. I always assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>**+**<kbd>Shift</kbd>**+**<kbd>T</kbd> for it too.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>**+**<kbd>Alt</kbd>**+**<kbd>S</kbd> to go to settings and search for `reopen clo...`and assign a new shortcut to the command under `Keymap`section.

[image: PhpStorm Keymap panel reopen closed file tab]

Additionally [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/opening-and-reopening-files-in-the-editor.html#reopen) may come in handy too.

> To open a recently opened file, choose **View | Recent Files** on the main
>   menu or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>**+**<kbd>E</kbd>. Then select the desired file from the **Recent**
>   **Files** pop-up window, that opens.

Comment: In that case, you can use `[Ctrl]+[E]` to open any file, and then use `[Ctrl]+[Shift]+[T]` to reopen tabs in order they are closed. So you would get all the tabs back as usual. This is a workaround but still a convenient one IMO. Otherwise shortcut does not seem to work when no files is opened.

Comment: For Mac: (Cmd + ,) for settings. Then I prefer Cmd + Shift + T

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+T` is already used by `Main Menu > Navigate > Go to Test`

Answer (score 34):

In addition to Umur's answer, PhpStorm has the convenient [Ctrl-E shortcut](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/ctrl.html) for [Recent Files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/navigating-to-recent-file.html) which is already bound by default. It's not restricted to closed files, though, but it's still very convenient to move around between opened or recently closed files.