# PhpStorm reopen closed tab

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I have PhpStorm 2017.2.1 and when I want to reopen a recently closed tab (CMD + Shift + Tab - Chrome feature) it opens the closed file in the current tab. Anyone experiencing this behaviour?

Comment: What action it's mapped to? The `Settings/Preferences | Keymap` screen has a button (next to the search field) where IDE can show what actions have that shortcut assigned. In general -- you can also use `View | Recent Files...` and it will show recently used/closed files -- the most recent should be selected by default.

Comment: Main menu | Window | Editor Tabs | Reopen Closed Tab - This is the action mapped to. I remember I have mapped it myself so it matches the one in chrome. The thing is that until a few months ago when I pressed it it reopened the closed tab in a new tab, now it does the same thing just that it does it in the current tab

Comment: In such case I do not know (it still works fine here on Windows 10 / 2017.2.4). I suggest disabling all custom (not bundled by default) plugins to see how it will behave there. And try checking with standard GUI Theme. My main suspicion: custom GUI theme (be it bundled or custom (e.g. Material or Afterglow plugins)) or some plugin (UI related). No bright ideas on what standard setting may introduce such behaviour (unless, perhaps it has something to do with tab limit -- just a random thought though...).

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to do anything custom you can use CMD + E which will pull up your recent files that you had open. You can then browse through them and re-open whichever tab that you wish.

If you want to add a Keymap entry. Go to Preferences -> Keymap and search for "Reopen" and add a shortcut there. (I'm not 100% sure which version this was added in so its possible you may not have this option)

[image]

This question is also likely a duplicate of [How to open recently closed file in PhpStorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41895392/how-to-open-recently-closed-file-in-phpstorm)