# How somehow show which file(s) were active priorly?

Tags: phpstorm

Working with PhpStorm 2021.1 I have a lot of files opened and when I open some other file if
there is a way somehow show which file(s) were opened/active priorly?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `Ctrl-E`/`Cmd-E`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41895448/410939.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open recently closed file in PhpStorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41895392/how-to-open-recently-closed-file-in-phpstorm)